# Where do I increase the torch timer?

Tags: dark-souls-2

There is a timer running while having the torch lit. I remember picking up torches early in the game, but have not found any since and now I only have a couple of minutes left.

Where do I find torches and is there any other way to increase the timer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Torches can be found in various places around the game world as items. In addition, enemies that carry torches (there is one on one of the bridges in the Hunters Copse, and a few more in the Gutter, to name a couple of places) have a high chance of dropping a torch upon death.